# How to show a validation message that the field is required?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I have this Embeded code:

```
<div class="widget_wrapper">
  <div class="ewp_form_container ewp_widget_container" webinar_id="nKtrYSnYq7q6PiRYiCrfxw==" >
  </div> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ewpcdn-ecs.easywebinar.com/widget/js/ewp_widget.js?v=2.1.857" ></script>
</div>
```

which generated form and i want to show the users that the filed is required if they left out the required field blank. For now it only shows the border color in red upon left out the required filed but i want a proper message that the field is required.

I tried to validate using jQuery but it not working for me.

Comment: Can you show more of your codes, so it can be checked what is missing?

Comment: If https://ewpcdn-ecs.easywebinar.com is not your website, then you can't do anything with the form you don't control.